# How to properly close a QWidget-window in an API with PythonQt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside, qtgui, pythonqt

i'm working with Python 2.7 in the API of a visualization-program. In its 2016-version i created a GUI with PySide and it was working guite good. Now in their new 2017-version they changed from PySide to PythonQt, so my imports and a few commands had to be changed, but it still works so far.

But if i close my GUI and try to proceed working, for example opening a current or new project the 2017-version is exiting, sometimes with, sometimes without error message, but that message does not help at all.

If i close my GUI-window the same way as in the 2016-version, the program is closed. The strange thing is that if i use the close command that i would need if i run my window standalone in Windows 7 Pro an error is shown in the program (Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1152, in closeEvent ValueError: slot quit() -> void requires QApplication instance as first argument.), my GUI is closed and i can continue working.

So i my GUI needs to be closed in a certain way, that i could not figure out so far.

My GUI is opened by calling the showMyGUI()-function in the programs terminal, where python commands can be executed or by pressing an F-button, where this function is linked to.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, os
progVers = getVredVersion()[:1]
if progVers == "8": #2016-version
    from PySide.QtCore import *
    from PySide.QtGui import *
elif progVers == "9": #2017-version
    from PythonQt.QtCore import *
    from PythonQt.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        ...

        self.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        progVers = getVredVersion()[:1]
        if progVers == "8":      
            QApplication.instance().quit()
        elif progVers == "9":
            QApplication.quit() #as used for standalone in Windows 7 Pro
        event.accept()

def showMyGUI():   
    app = QApplication.instance()
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()

keyF11 = vrKey(Key_F11)
keyF11.connect(showMyGUI)
```

Can anyone tell me how to close my GUI properly?

Comment: can't you use standard `self.close()` to close `MainWindow` and it will end `QApplication` too.

Comment: Already tried that, but as i mentioned above this shuts down the whole program when i try to continue working. But i found a solution now. `MainWindow` is now inheriting form `QDialog` and needs a parent (`def __init__(self, parent=None):` and `super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)`). When creating the `MainWindow`-object the parent-window can be accessed with `verdMainWindow()` in the 2016-version an with `vrMainWindow` in the 2017-version. Just found out about that, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hey @JFT, add the answer to your post and then vote it answered a couple of days after!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is:
`MainWindow` is now inheriting form `QDialog` and needs a parent (`def __init__(self, parent=None`): and `super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)`). When creating the `MainWindow`-object the parent-window can be accessed with `verdMainWindow()` in the 2016-version an with `vrMainWindow` in the 2017-version. I create an object of that class in this way `window=MainWindow(vrMainWindow)`.